# Is every affine open subset of a locally Noetherian scheme also Noetherian?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, schemes

Ravi Vakil definition 5.3.4.

> Suppose $X$ is a scheme. If $X$ can be covered by affine open sets Spec($A$) where $A$ is Noetherian, we say that $X$ is a **locally Noetherian scheme**.

The definition only says "*If $X$ can be covered by affine open sets Spec($A$) where $A$ is Noetherian*". I wonder if this can imply that every affine open set is Noetherian?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, because an affine scheme is quasicompact.  So, if $U\subseteq X$ is an affine open subscheme, then $U$ is covered by *finitely* many spectra of Noetherian rings and so is Noetherian.